# Top nth of a report with rest as other

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a query that shows total amount by supplier. I want a report where the top 9 are shown and the rest is added together under an "other" supplier. Thus the detail shows top 9 suppliers, other groups the rest and the total on the report includes all.

I cant get the top 9 but how to I get the "other"

I use MS Access 2007

---

#### EDIT:

I also need to add a company name that is in another register. `t_costed` has the value, linked to `t_register_2bre` that has the company, linked to `t_contacts_company` that had the company name.

I know the amount of columns returned by the `select` query must be equal in the two unioned queries but I'm struggling with the `INNER JOIN`.

[image: Relationship]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `union` query in the following way:

```sql
select top 9 t.amount
from table1 t
order by t.amount desc
union all
select sum(u.amount)
from table1 u
where 
u.amount < 
(
    select min(v.amount) 
    from 
    (select top 9 w.amount from table1 w order by w.amount desc) v
)
```

Here, change all references to `table1` with the name of your table.

---

**EDIT:**

With the additional information provided in your question, I would suggest the following (untested) SQL:

```sql
select top 9 c.company, t.amount
from 
    (t_costed t inner join t_register_2bre r on t.eventidbre = r.id_bre) 
    inner join t_contacts_company c on r.defaulting_partyid = c.id_contacts_company
order by t.amount desc
union all
select "Others" as company, sum(u.amount)
from t_costed u
where 
u.amount < 
(
    select min(v.amount) 
    from 
    (select top 9 w.amount from t_costed w order by w.amount desc) v
)
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you. I need to add a company name that is in another register. Costed has the value, linked to register that has the company, linked to contacts that had the company name. I know the amount of select must equal the two joined queries but I'm struggling with the INNER JOIN.

Comment: @ShawnLotriet-Homann Please edit your original question with this new information and include a relationship diagram of your database tables.

Comment: Hi added the relationship tables image.

Comment: I have updatedmy SQL query but it asks for a missing parameter at r.defaulting_partyID

Comment: @ShawnLotriet-Homann This would typically imply that the field `defaulting_partyID ` is not recognised - have I spelt the fieldnames correctly?

Comment: Hi Lee Mac, thank you very much it works, however the totals seem odd. It is duplicating certain Companies and when i check my excel it is incorrect.Could it be because of the Union command? How is it selecting the amounts to total? It needs to group on company and the total the amounts and then select the top 9 with the rest in OTHER.